# Making a UIView update behind another one in the same view controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cocoapods, quartz-core

I'm working in swift to make an app the uses the cocoapod framework [`BBSlideoutMenu`](http://bergerbytes.io/cocoapods/bbslideoutmenu/) to display a menu. I am also using the cocoapod framework `ChameleonFramework`. What I'm trying to do is make the hamburger button that I'm using change colour when it is opened. I haven't yet implemented it, but I also want to make the bar on top transparent. I've recorded it [here](https://gfycat.com/SillyDimpledBull) so you can see what is happening. Basically, the view only gets updated when I slide away the menu.

Disclaimer: I am aware that using a hamburger menu is viewed as bad code design, unfortunately it is what I need in this app.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import BBSlideoutMenu
import ChameleonFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController, BBSlideoutMenuDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var slideMenu: BBSlideoutMenu!


    var button: HamburgerButton! = nil
    var menuOpen = false;
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let topBar = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.1))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        topBar.backgroundColor = FlatRed()
        button = HamburgerButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 54, 54))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleMenu(_:)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        topBar.addSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(topBar)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        slideMenu.setupEdgePan()
        slideMenu.slideDirection = .Right
        slideMenu.shrinkAmount = 0
        slideMenu.slideTravelPercent = 0.87
        slideMenu.menuOffset = 0
        slideMenu.zoomFactor = 1
        slideMenu.springEnabled = false
        slideMenu.backgroundColor = FlatRed()
        slideMenu.delegate = self
        slideMenu.setupEdgePan()
    }

    func toggleMenu(sender : HamburgerButton!) {
        if(menuOpen) {
            slideMenu.dismissSlideMenu(animated: true, time: nil)
        } else {
            slideMenu.presentSlideMenu(true) { () -> Void in
                //Runs after menu is presented
            }
        }
    }

    func didPresentBBSlideoutMenu(menu: BBSlideoutMenu) {
        menuOpen = true
        button.changeColor(UIColor.blackColor())
    }

    func didDismissBBSlideoutMenu(menu: BBSlideoutMenu) {
        menuOpen = false
        button.changeColor(UIColor.whiteColor())
    }

}
```

I am using [this hamburger menu button](https://github.com/robb/hamburger-button), which has been created with `CoreGraphics` and `QuartzCore`, and have added the following function for change colour.

```
func changeColor(color: UIColor) {
        for layer in [ self.topStroke, self.middleStroke, self.bottomStroke ] {
            layer.fillColor = nil
            layer.strokeColor = color.CGColor
            layer.lineWidth = 4
            layer.miterLimit = 4
            layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
            layer.masksToBounds = true

            let strokingPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(layer.path, nil, 4, .Round, .Miter, 4)

            layer.bounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(strokingPath)

            layer.actions = [
                "strokeStart": NSNull(),
                "strokeEnd": NSNull(),
                "transform": NSNull()
            ]

            self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        }
    }
```

Edit: I have tried using `setNeedsDisplay` on the button, the topBar, and both of them consecutively in the functions `toggleMenu`, `didPresentBBSlideoutMenu` and `didDismissBBSlideoutMenu` and it didn't work

I have also tried calling it on the actual view (self.view)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setNeedsDisplay` the button.

Comment: I've tried this, it didn't work. I'll add a note saying that to the description.